# Ember.js - Model inside component

Tags: javascript, ember.js, model, components

I am making an app just for practice and i have a doubt in a component's function "didReceiveAttr". When i pass my MODEL in my template and then i erase some element in it the function doesnt work, but if i pass "model.length" in the template and then erase something the function work!

My component template

```
<h1>Tasks ({{totalTask}})</h1>
```

My component JS

```
  totalTask: null,

  didReceiveAttrs(){
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.set('totalTask', this.get('model.length'));
    console.log(this.get('model'));
  }
```

My primary template

```
{{task-list model=model}}
```

or

```
{{task-list model=model.length}}
```

Comment: I guess your question is about why this happens? I tried to explain it in my answer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed the expected behavior; just look at [Ember guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/#toc_formatting-component-attributes-with-code-didreceiveattrs-code) about how `didReceiveAttrs` works. It is clearly stated that "`didReceiveAttrs` hook is called every time a component's attributes are updated". When you add to or remove from an array the array itself does not change; hence `didReceiveAttrs` is not executed. It is only executed when the initial assignment to `model` is performed.

I prepared this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/2e51ec169d33160a3c6ca191d18838e2?openFiles=templates.components.my-component.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs) to illustrate you a better ember way to handle this case. You should rely on computed properties as much as you can; hence I added `computedTotalTask` as a computed property to `my-component.js` and it relies on `model.length` as you can see.

Comment: yes, i understand that didReceiveAttrs only is call when an update is made, thats why i have the confusion because i consider that (removing the task) an update to the model length and for that should call the function

Comment: sorry, i do not get what you are getting confused about. As I explained the official guide says `didReceiveAttrs` only gets executed when an attribute is updated. Adding/removing an array does not update the array itself; but the length of the array is updated. So; if you pass the array as the attribute `didReceiveAttrs` will not trigger upon addition/removal of items. If you pass the length of the array; since addition/removal of items change the length; `didReceiveAttrs` gets executed as expected.

Comment: thank for your reply, yes i get it now, the problem was that i saw the model's length like an attribute and when i delete or add something in the model, this attribute (length) was updated, therefore the function have to be called, but i see that doesn't fit

Comment: i am glad that you got it; do not forget to accept/upvote answers that helped you. best regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{task-list modelLength=model.length}}
```

Here you are assigning`model.length` as `modelLength` property to the component. so initially didReceiveAttrs will be called as component is receiving `modelLength` property and when you add one more element to model then `modelLength` property itself changed so this will invoke `didReceiveAttrs` before re-render.

```
{{task-list modelTaskList=model}}
```

Here modelTaskList is pointing to array, so when you add/remove item through KVO compliant method such as pushObject it will be reflected in component too. but the modelTaskList is still pointing to the same array so didReceiveAttrs hook will not be called. 
Suppose if you assigned different array then you can see the didReceiveAttrs is called.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just set this as a computed property, ensuring updates in the event of the bound variable being updated.

Within your component, set up a computed property that will watch for a change to your model, then update the variable `modelLength` with the change

```
modelLength: Ember.computed('model', function(){
  return this.get('model').length;
}
```

Then, within your handlebars template, reference this length

```
<h1>Tasks{{#if modelLength}} ({{modelLength}}){{/if}}</h1>
```